# Windows 8 Storage Space Recovery

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, file-recovery, storage-spaces

the problem start like this.

I add a 2-way mirror storage pool in my Windows 8. (consist of 2 x 500gb harddisk) I assume it can be read by any OS. So, I proceed to hackintosh my computer.

After hackintosh, I found that I can't read my storage pool harddisk. I install Windows 8 on Parallels Desktop and connect the two harddisks to the Windows 8 VM. It still doesn't able to mount the storage pool back. I tried the "Get-VirtualDisk" and "Get-StoragePool", it can't detect anything. Also the recovery software from "http://www.storage-spaces-recovery.com/". It can't detect either.

I didn't format or do anything to the harddisk. So, how can I recover my Storage Space Pool? Hope someone can help me as I don't want to lose all the precious files :(

Comment: Restore from your regular backups.

Comment: I thought the storage pool is reliable enough so I don't have any other backup for that. Who knows :(